# How can we retrieve attention mask from the deep learning model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, model

Hi I want to visualize what my model has learned and want to get a attention mask from my model. May I ask how can I do this?

Below is my desire output.
[image]

From paper [New perspectives on plant disease characterization based on deep learning]

Answer (score 0):

The method that they apply is cited in the paper:

> **6.1.1. Qualitative results**
> [...] we used one of the visualization methods presented in (Yosinski et al., 2015) [...].

From a quick glimpse, it looks like [Yosinski et. al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.06579) visualize the magnitude of pixels of a particular feature map. The authors of your referenced paper provide more detail how exactly they produced the results:

> More precisely, we started by plotting
> the position of the neuron with the highest activation for all the features
> maps extracted from the last convolutional layer, and from there we
> accumulated the first 30 dominant activations and matched them to the
> original image.
> [[Lee et. al.]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168169919300560)